# How would I make a discord bot DM someone that it just kicked?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a joke feature for a discord bot where if there is no 2nd argument to the kick command it will just kick a certain member and then DM them an invite link to the server.

```
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'kick':

            const user = message.mentions.users.first()

            if(user){
                const member = message.mentions.members.first();

                if(member){
                    member.kick('Kicked because someone told me to').then(() =>{
                        message.channel.send(`The user ${user.tag} was kicked`);
                    }).catch(err =>{
                        message.channel.send('I was unable to kick that person')
                        console.log(err);
                    });

                    }else{
                        message.channel.send('The user mentioned was not in this hell hole')
                    }
                }else{
                    message.channel.send('Since no valid name was given, Imma just kick Cameron instead')
                    message.channel.send('*kick <@549777121476608000>')
                    message.author.send("message")
                    deletetimer = setTimeout(remove, 980)
                    function remove () {
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(2)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
)
```

Comment: Please use workplace-appropriate language on Stack Overflow, not language which may be offensive to some people or groups of people. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites). Keep in mind that using offensive language tends to result in people reacting poorly to your posts (i.e. they may downvote). In addition, do you really want a future employer to see you using such language in a situation which is intended to be professional?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

You can just use:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const user = member.user;
```

`message.author.send` refers to the person calling the command, you will need to get the member from the id and then send the message

```js
else {
    //message.guild.members.get if you are using v11
    const cameron = message.guild.members.cache.get("549777121476608000");
    message.channel.send('Since no valid name was given, Imma just kick Cameron instead');

    cameron.send("Here's the invite: ")
        //sincey you already have the variable might aswell use .kick instead of sending '*kick <@549777121476608000>'
        .then(() => cameron.kick("Reason"))
        .catch(console.error);

    deletetimer = setTimeout(remove, 980);

    function remove() {
        //since you aren't sending '*kick <@549777121476608000>' anymore its 1, not 2
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
    }
}
```